# Can I run Jest through the Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular6, angular-cli, jestjs

I have configured my Angular 6 application to run tests with Jest when I run "npm run test". This works fine.
I'd like to be able to run those same tests when I execute "ng test". Is it possible to configure the Angular CLI to do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for this https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/jest

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend using the [Jest builder](https://github.com/meltedspark/angular-builders/tree/master/packages/jest) if you want to switch to Jest in your Angular CLI project. We just had a migration from Karma to Jest in one of our projects, it worked like a charm. For reference, here are the minimal steps to switch to Jest in a new project:

1. Create the project

   ```
   $ ng new myapp
   $ cd myapp
   ```
2. Remove Karma dependencies, config file and `test.ts`:

   ```
   $ yarn remove karma karma-chrome-launcher karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter karma-jasmine karma-jasmine-html-reporter
   $ rm src/karma.conf.js src/test.ts
   ```
3. Install Jest builder, create the config file:

   ```
   $ yarn add --dev jest @angular-builders/jest
   $ touch src/jest.config.js
   ```
4. Switch to `commonjs` in the `src/tsconfig.spec.json`:

   ```json
   {
     "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
     "compilerOptions": {
       "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
       "module": "commonjs",
       "types": [
         "jasmine",
         "node"
       ]
     },
     "include": [
       "**/*.spec.ts",
       "**/*.d.ts"
     ]
   }
   ```
5. Switch to Jest builder in `angular.json`:

   ```json
   {
     ...
       "test": {
         "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
         "options": {
           "styles": [
             "src/styles.css"
           ],
           "scripts": [],
           "assets": [
             "src/favicon.ico",
             "src/assets"
           ]
         }
       },
     ...
   }
   ```

Now you will be running the tests with Jest:

```
$ ng test
 PASS  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  AppComponent
    ✓ should create the app (223ms)
    ✓ should have as title 'myapp' (80ms)
    ✓ should render title in a h1 tag (70ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.704s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: just a small correction. Use the correct types in `tsconfig.spec.json`. The  `"types"` array should just have `jest` in place of `"jasmine","node"`